# How to add contact form on category page?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, layout, blocks, contact-form

I have to add custom contact form on product listing page.For this i am adding in `local.xml` file.

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content"> 
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" as="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

But it is not displaying anything.

Answer (score 1):

On top of what Prashant suggested, I reckon you don't need to re add the blocks to the `content`.

Instead of:

```
<reference name="content"> 
    <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
            <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" as="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </block>
</reference>
```

You should do:

```
<reference name="product_list"> 
    <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" as="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

In **app/design/frontend/Your-theme/Your-package/catalog/product/list.phtml**

add below code

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('contactForm');
```